# Is it possible to use Content URIs on a wearable to refer to content on the phone?

Tags: android, wear-os

If I have a `URI` referring to local content on a phone, such as `content://com.myapp/someimage` then using this url on a wearable device doesn't work (such as passing it to `ImageView`'s `setImageURI()` or using it with an `InputStream` in conjunction with a `BitmapFactory`, stuff that does work if executed on the phone).

I guess the code is trying to look for the content on the watch rather than on the phone, is there therefore a way the `URI` can be amended so that the content will be searched for on the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right when you assume that the system try to resolve the `URI` on the watch.

To display content that is stored on the other device (in either way), you have to synchronize it with the `DataLayer`.
You can find how to do it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html).